# Custom view (swipeView) not resizing properly after orientation change

Tags: android, swipeview

I'm using SwipeView (http://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-swipeview/) inside my activity's layout to display several pages. Moreover, I want to handle the orientation changes manually so I added

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

into the application's manifest, so that onDestroy/onCreate are not called. Unfortunately, by doing this, the elements inside the swipeview are not resized accordingly. I already tried the following methods:

- invalidate
- requestLayout
- forceLayout

None of them did the trick!
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: A layout xml file and the manifest would probably be a good starting point to provide for us to take a quick look at.  Once the changes are disabled, several aspects become our own responsibility and caught and managed within onConfigurationChanged() usually.  Or it could be a small hiccup in the layout structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone struggles with this, I finally found a solution.
The trick was to request layout not on the swipeview itself but rather on getChildContainer().

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    SwipeView swipeView = (SwipeView)findViewById(R.id.swipeView);
    int pageWidth = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    swipeView.setPageWidth(pageWidth);
    for ( int i = 0; i < swipeView.getChildContainer().getChildCount(); i++ )
        swipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width = pageWidth;
    swipeView.getChildContainer().requestLayout();
    swipeView.scrollToPage(swipeView.getCurrentPage());     
}
```